# Break time in JavaScript, and get the rest script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am retrieving a text file by lines using jQuery.

I would like to have a break of 10 seconds at line 5. I'm using the `setInterval()` function, but there is a 10 second break in the background and the lines of the file are still loading.

Is there any other function that can set a break in the script for 10 seconds and display it in the form of 10 ... 9 ... 8 ... 7 etc. After reaching '0' the next 5 lines should be collected.

Comment: Can you please give us some code to work on? I mean the JS script you're refering to ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
var count = 9;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ getLines() }, 1000);

function getLines() {
    if(count > 0){ 
        alert(count);
        count--;
    }
    else{
        // get your lines
    }
}
```

You can provide code so I can help you with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, worked hard and developed a little script that you can see below.

```
<script>
var TimeBreak;
var myInterval;
var DivNameWithCount = 1;

function LoadFile()
{   
    $.get("<?php echo base_url('getfilecontent/line'); ?>", function(response) 
    {

        var logfile = response;

        if(logfile == "")
        {
            $("#ObjectShow").append("<div style=\"padding: 2px; padding-left: 8px;\">End of file.</div>");
            $('#ObjectShow').scrollTop($('#ObjectShow')[0].scrollHeight);
        }
        else if(logfile.indexOf("[break_time]") > -1)
        {
            TimeBreak = 10;
            DivNameWithCount++;
            $("#ObjectShow").append("<div style=\"padding: 2px; padding-left: 8px;\" id=\"CountLayer" + DivNameWithCount + "\"></div>");
            $('#ObjectShow').scrollTop($('#ObjectShow')[0].scrollHeight);
            myInterval = setInterval(function(){ setBreakIn() }, 1000);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#ObjectShow").append("<div style=\"padding: 2px; padding-left: 8px;\">" + logfile + "</div>");
            $('#ObjectShow').scrollTop($('#ObjectShow')[0].scrollHeight);
            LoadFile();
        }
    });
}

function setBreakIn() 
{
    if(TimeBreak > 0)
    { 
        $("#CountLayer" + DivNameWithCount).html(TimeBreak.toString());
        TimeBreak--;
    }
    else
    {
        LoadFile();
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}

LoadFile();
</script>
```